# Adding Event To Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events

I am procedurally generating buttons via code-behind and I wanted to add an eventhandler to the click event. I struggled greatly to make this happen and think there should be a better/cleaner/easier way than what I did? Please help!

```
public class PatientButtonCreator
{
    public PatientButtonCreator() { }
    public Button CreatePatientButton(PatientFolder.Patient pt, MainWindow mw)
    {
        Button btn = new Button() { Content = sp };//stackpanel of labels of patient info added to button content
        btn.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(mw.PatientSelectionRoutedEventHandler));
    }
}

public MainWindow(Profile profile)
{
    //...
    public void PatientSelectionRoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//populated to every patient button
    {
        //each patient object is made into a button and added to PatientListStackPanel on the mainWindow
        PatientListStackPanel = profile.RetrievePatientButtons(this, PatientListStackPanel);
        Patient pt = ((((sender as Button).Content as StackPanel).Children[0] as Label).DataContext as Patient);
        //the above line is how I finally got access to the patient, but believe this is very ugly. The object hierarchy is Button has content of a stackpanel which has children of labels which have datacontext of specific Patient objects...
        SelectPatient(pt);//goal function to execute on button_click event
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

public class Profile
{
    List<PatientFolder.Patient> patients = new List<PatientFolder.Patient>(); //goal was for patient list to be private to all other objects
    public StackPanel RetrievePatientButtons(MainWindow mw, StackPanel ptListSP)
    {
        //...
        ptListSP.Children.Clear();
        View.PatientButtonCreator pbc = new View.PatientButtonCreator();
        foreach (PatientFolder.Patient pt in patients)
            ptListSP.Children.Add(pbc.CreatePatientButton(pt, mw));
        return ptListSP;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about the XAML and MVVM pattern. But if you must have to do it, you can do it like this:

```
private void Method()
{
    btn.Click += Btn_Click;
}

private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something ...
}
```

Simply add event handler to Click event. 
You can read more about Button class and his events in [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.button).